# Js var, not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys for some reason this variable wont work on my file. I have a picture, and when the user hovers over it, its suppose to bring up a swipe box with some information about the pic. However the box wont appear for some reason.

HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = $('.modal');

    modal.hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

    alsolike(
      "qEybdR", "Checkbox Radial Wash",
      "dPdoNp", "Google Messenger Icon Button",
      "BJAjF", "Masonry Multi Column Grid"
    );
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="drib" href="http://drbl.in/okRS">View it on Dribbble <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="category">First Drive Review</div>
      <h2>2015 Dodge Challenger SRT Hellcat</h2>
      <h4>Andy Wendler <span>from</span> July 2014</h4>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <p>Make room, Beelzebub, there’s a new demon-prince pony car in town, and it’s from the people who once brought you a real Demon. Known in this mortal realm as the Dodge Challenger SRT Hellcat...</p><a href="http://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/2015-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-first-drive-review">Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.modal .image-container {
  background: url("http://media.caranddriver.com/images/14q3/612022/2015-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-first-drive-review-car-and-driver-photo-615298-s-original.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.modal .content {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40%;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.modal .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px;
}
.modal .wrapper h2 {
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 8px 0 10px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.modal .wrapper h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.modal .wrapper h4 span {
  text-transform: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
}
.modal .wrapper .category {
  background: #333;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
          transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.modal .wrapper .line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #E3000C;
  margin: 16px 0 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.modal .wrapper p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
          transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.modal .wrapper p span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.modal .wrapper a {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999;
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  margin-top: 12px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal .wrapper a i.fa {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #E3000C;
}
.modal .wrapper a:hover {
  color: #E3000C;
}
.modal .wrapper a:hover i.fa {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.modal.open .image-container {
  width: 60%;
}
.modal.open .content {
  right: 0;
}
.modal.open .content .category {
  top: 0;
}
.modal.open .content h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.modal.open .content h4 {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal.open .content .line {
  width: 90px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal.open .content p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal.open .content a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.drib {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.drib .fa {
  color: #ea4c89;
}

body {
  background: #777;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like your script is running before you've included jquery - so `$` won't be defined and you should be getting an error in your browser's console telling you this.

Comment: Move the script block with the modal part at the bottom of the page, right before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Tried this already, still nothing

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: `alert(x); var x = 5; // uh, well, yeah, of course it doesn't work.`

Comment: Kevin the code it self works, its the way i was putting it, Freedorm was right

Comment: @RobotMan Yes, my comment was re-enforcing freedomn's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jquery until you have included jquery, ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var modal = $('.modal');
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

must be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var modal = $('.modal');
</script>
```

there's still some debate as to the best place to put these (in the `<head>` (so available to the page) or just before `</body>` (so the content loads quicker)) as long as they are in the correct order.

Comment: *"its the way i was putting it, Freedomn-m **was right**"* - not sure why it deserved a downvote...